# What study materials can a layperson use to gain a deeper understanding of lung cancer?

Tags: cancer, lungs

I am an outsider to the medical sciences, yet now in desperate need of knowledge to help a family member with lung cancer navigate the difficult medical system in our country.  I would like to develop the knowledge to be able to read up on, and have educated discussions on treatment options.  I have a great deal of time for reading and am confident of my ability to study the background material.

As a layperson, what study materials could help me gain a deeper understanding of lung cancer?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Generally, recommendation requests are off topic on almost every SE site. I've [posed the question on meta](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/do-we-want-to-allow-recommendation-questions) to get a community consensus.

Comment: @JohnP I edited the Q to make it more adherent to site guidelines - though I do realize it is still a recommendations type Q that is by nature opinion-based, I feel it had potential to help others seek knowledge on their own.

Comment: @Gordon The article you linked to seems reasonable, but the site in general is a bunch of click bait. (That's why they broke the article into 11 pages unnecessarily - to present more ads.) The same information can be found on more reputable sites that don't sell supplements. We prefer such sites here. Also, answering in comments is to be avoided.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Comment: @DoctorWhom this is much better. I think the consensus is that recommendation requests are off topic, but this I think dodges that nicely.

Comment: @Gordon - You are free to criticize the moderators as much as you like, as long as you follow the "be nice" policy. The meta discussion has nothing to do with either law or medicine. It is pretty much established policy on every SE site (With some specific exceptions) that "Recommend me a X" questions are off topic. They don't get a consensus answer, and generally are a bunch of "Well, I like this" which does not fit the SE question/answer model. Rather than just hammer it closed, I opened it up for consideration on meta. (Where the consensus is close them).

Comment: @Gordon I would remind you of the [be nice policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback). Name calling and insults are not okay.

Comment: @lynnyo I read 30722 Lung Cancer: Diagnosis and Management I found it really useful

Answer (score 6):

Cancer can be one of the most complicated concepts in medicine, not only because of the pathophysiology of cancer, but the complicated statistics involved in the epidemiology of the diseases and interpreting the results of studies on treatments.

If your previous studies have been completely outside of the biological sciences, it will be very difficult to gain the degree of understanding that you seem to want.  Even if you have some biology background, at best, you should definitely not expect to gain the expertise to confidently second-guess actual medical providers.

However, I applaud you for your desire to understand as much as possible, and you certainly may be able to learn enough to follow along in conversations about risks and benefits of different treatment options, and to have educated discussions about what is going on with your loved one.

You might FIRST START with patient education websites from the NIH or CDC on the basics of lung cancer, then fill in the gaps of details and background needed using textbooks on the underlying concepts.

For that, these are some of the more popular texts used in medical school, if you are able to get your hands on them, which have good sections on lung cancer.

- Robbins and Cotran: Pathological Basis for Disease (or [Robbins Basic Pathology](https://www.elsevier.com/books/robbins-basic-pathology/kumar/978-0-323-35317-5))
- West: Pulmonology [Physiology](https://books.google.com/books/about/West_s_Respiratory_Physiology.html?id=Wtj_oQEACAAJ&source=kp_cover) and also [Pathophysiology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1451107137)
- Harrison's Principles of Internal Medicine

Advancing your understanding of the mechanisms underlying cancer development and progression:

- Pathoma (the sections on oncogenesis are fantastic)

I would also do some reading on how to interpret the statistics pertinent to cancer, such as odds ratio, relative risk, number needed to treat, sensitivity/specificity, incidence, mortality rates, 5 year survival rates, etc.  Statistics are not taught well in most schools these days and additional knowledge is important to being able to understand how decisions are made.